# Convert javascript into jquery - .append() and .html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have code in js, but i don't know how to convert in into jquery :(

```
if (document.getElementById("getit").value != ""){
         txt = "";
         txt += "blabla";
         txt += document.getElementById("getit").value;
         txt += "blabla2\n";
         document.getElementById("generator").value += txt;
         }
```

could someone help me with it ?:)
I tried with .append() and .html() but it didn't work :/

Comment: Please include the code that doesn't work too. Can't tell you what mistake was made otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is that how convert question's block to JQuery, this could be answer:

```
if $("#getit").val() != ""){
    txt = "";
    txt += "blabla";
    txt += $("#getit").val();
    txt += "blabla2\n";
    $("#generator").val($("#generator").val() + txt) ;
}
```

Comment: @user3062218: It's working but i don't know what's the advantages, it's depending on you that why want convert js to JQuery, maybe i don't figure out your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`append` and `html` are irrelevant to what you're doing. The jquery function that reads and writes the `value` attribute is called [`val`](https://api.jquery.com/val/).

```
var v = $('#getit').val(), g = $('#generator');
if (v) g.val(g.val() + 'blala' + v + 'blabla2\n');
```